# 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Tags: python, pandas

After using groupby function I want to convert that to a dataframe object but it shows error

My Code

```
     dfgrp1 = df['Service 1'].groupby(['Service Type'])
     dfgrp1 = dfgrp1.to_frame()
```

Output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [18], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 dfgrp1 = df['Service 1'].groupby(['Service Type'])
----> 2 dfgrp1 = dfgrp1.to_frame()

File ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py:904, in GroupBy.__getattr__(self, attr)
    901 if attr in self.obj:
    902     return self[attr]
--> 904 raise AttributeError(
    905     f"'{type(self).__name__}' object has no attribute '{attr}'"
    906 )

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'to_frame'
```

*P.S. I have multiple sheets in the excel workbook I don't think that would be a problem but just mentioning it in case it does affect.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply aggregation to the grouped result first.
for instance, **dfgrp1** what does it produces when you print it? an object reference, which you cannot make into frame.
However, the result that you see as result of groupby, employing agregation, will allow you to use to_frame()